# Extract a list of values from a column in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, regex

I’m trying to extract a list of values from a column in a dataframe.

For example:

```py
# dataframe with "num_fruit" column 
fruit_df = pd.DataFrame({"num_fruit": ['1 "Apple"', 
                                        '100 "Peach Juice3" 1234 "Not_fruit" 23 "Straw-berry" 2 "Orange"']})
```

```bash
# desired output: a list of values from the "num_fruit" column 
[['1 "Apple"'],
 ['100 "Peach Juice3"', '1234 "Not_fruit"', '23 "Straw-berry"', '2 "Orange"']]
```

Any suggestions? Thanks a lot.

What I’ve tried:

```py
import re 

def split_fruit_val(val):
    return re.findall('(\d+ ".+")', val)

result_list = []
for val in fruit_df['num_fruit']:
    result = split_fruit_val(val)
    result_list.append(result)

print(result_list)
```

```py
#output: some values were not split appropriately 
[['1 "Apple"'],
 ['100 "Peach Juice3" 1234 "Not_fruit" 23 "Straw-berry" 2 "Orange"']]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets `split` with positive lookahead for a number

```
fruit_df['num_fruit'].str.split(r'\s(?=\d+)')
```

---

```
0                                          [1 "Apple"]
1    [100 "Peach Juice3", 1234 "Not_fruit", 23 "Str...
Name: num_fruit, dtype: object
```

Comment: A small addition:`fruit_df['num_fruit'].str.split(r'\s(?=\d+)').values.tolist()` could be added to match desired output.

Comment: Amazing. Which regex can I use if "Peach Juice3"is changed to ""Peach Juice 3 (250~500ml)"?

Comment: @Stella I think something like this should work: `fruit_df['num_fruit'].str.split(r'(?<=")\s(?=\d+)')`